# Is there Arquillian h2/database bootstrap support unrelated to JPA?

Tags: h2, jboss-arquillian

I'm using Arquillian for integration testing tomcat apps, and it works great for the web archive and configurations.

I'm also using the inmemdb-maven-plugin for H2 setup during the maven-failsafe verification/integration test run, that also works great.

But, Arquillian allows you to run the integration test as a unit test within the IDE (eclipse)...but this is where the breakdown occurs.  I have DataSource test code checking the db values during the integration test runs, but since H2 isn't bootstrapped by Arquillian, it's not bootstrapped in the Eclipse IDE unit-test scenario (But works fine in command-line and jenkins land).

Any possible leads how to get H2 bootstrapped in a way that would work for Arquillian, unit-testing, and maven integration testing?

Comment: Is your h2 database deployed as a separated process?

Comment: If it helps, sure, if it doesn't help, we can separate it.  Using the inmemdb-maven-plugin is the current deployment process.